adding git to visual Studio made original .sln file unusable
I have a working VS2022 Enterprise (NOT VSCODE) Solution on Windows 11-Pro. I wanted to add Source Control to it. MANY years ago, I had created a github account (DocDJ) which still holds an old repo. Using Github, I created a new private repo (M_exifier_threaded). I turned on Source Control (using git commands, because doing it with VS fails) and after 3 days of attempts, got my existing solution folder initialized and pushed to my git repo. Along the way, I must have done "something", that created a clone in an old local directory ("E:\GIT-personal-repos\DocDJ").
At this point, I can't open the original VS folder's .sln (all the old code and .git and .vs are still there), but I CAN open the Solution from "E:\GIT-personal-repos\DocDJ\M_exifier_threaded".
I was hoping to keep everything in the original folder if that is possible, so I could turn off Source Control and have only my latest version of the code in it. However, I do see the advantages of keeping my repo in a separate folder.
I have not made any changes to the code, so I am quite willing to start from scratch, if I can get that original solution working.
So my question is: can I fix my old VS folder so the code is usable (as-is) without GIT turned on (if I decide to stop using Source Control) and still use the code from the repo in the...DocDJ\ folder OR can I make the original folder usable with git and drop the folder in E:?
I tried to open the existing VS folder and got an error message that the .sln file is not a valid Solution file.
VS IS able to open the .sln in the cloned version, and after I switched views to Solutions rather than folder, the build worked.

" got my existing solution folder initialized and pushed to my git repo" Have you tried Cloning this url into a clean folder? Once cloned, you normally would see a list view containing available solutions to open, if not you could always try opening the .sln directly. Also, if you get this working and non-longer want to use version control at this location you can delete the .git folder at the root.

Yes, I cloned it and got the clone working, after telling VS to switch to Solution view. But the .sln in the ORIGINAL (VS) folder is now "not a valid Solution file". So I can't have my cake and eat it too. Maybe if I rename or delete the .git file in that old (VS) folder, it will work again. ANd I can have TWO "versions" of my solution.

hmm, not sure about that. I would compare the two .sln files and see what is going on with the one that does not load correctly.

The cloned project has the correct .sln file, the original file has only 3 lines: a git version identifier, an SHA key and a size number. It would appear that when I did a git initialization of the old folder, it removed all the VS info, I could try to copy the one from the git folder into it (saving "bad one" of course).

I looked inside the "git-version" of the .sln and saw references to GUID numbers and decided to NOT mess with the "now-bad" old .sln file. I can always use ordinary VS to re-build that whole project, if I need it. Unless someone  has an idea how to recover my old Solution, I will forge ahead with the git version.

You could look at the history of that specific file to see if you have changed it, or if whatever happened to it happened before the first commit. Git itself generally don't do changes to file unless going to a previous version, or merging.
